# How to get a UIViewController from a SwiftUI View in a UIKit Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

In my SwiftUI/UIKit project, we're using UIKit's Navigation Controller for navigation. Currently, I have a function that gets a UIViewController from a SwiftUI View:

```
func popTo<T: View>(viewType: T.Type, animated: Bool) {
    if let viewController = rootNavigationController.viewControllers.first(where: {
        $0.self.description.contains(String(describing: viewType))
    }) {
        self.rootNavigationController.popToViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

I want to make this more robust without relying on strings. I'd like to directly filter by the type. Here's an example:

```
if let firstHostingController = rootNavigationController.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is UIHostingController<MyView> }){
    self.popToView(viewController: firstHostingController, animated: true)
}
```

Given that we're working within a UIKit Navigation Controller, how can I modify my popTo function for this without using strings for type comparison?

Comment: SwiftUI has tools to declare navigation as state. Why not going declarative with the native tools for SwiftUI?

Comment: Given that we have more screens implemented in UIKit than SwiftUI, it's essential to navigate seamlessly between SwiftUI and UIKit screens. Could you provide a sample to illustrate what you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet is almost there. Just replace `MyView` with the type parameter `T`.

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func popTo<T: View>(viewType: T.Type, animated: Bool) {
        if let firstHostingController = viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is UIHostingController<T> }){
            self.popToViewController(firstHostingController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it before, and it did not work. When I replaced UIHostingController<T> with UIHostingController<AnyView>, it returned the first ViewController.

Comment: @Gus First, what's wrong with "it returned the first ViewController"? What did you expect it to do instead? What view controllers are even in the navigation stack before? Second, why did you "replace `UIHostingController<T>` with `UIHostingController<AnyView>`"? Why use `AnyView` here? What did you wanted to do? You are missing so many details for me to debug the problem, or even understand that there is a problem at all.

Comment: @Gus Please show a [mcve] of what is not working. Describe the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour of the code. Please *actually* apply my answer and not replace whatever you like with something random.

Comment: My intention in mentioning UIHostingController<AnyView> was to provide additional information that might spark new insights into the issue. 
I'll ensure to present a minimal reproducible example and describe the expected vs. actual behavior without unnecessary changes.